# Error occurred during price list product assignments build

Tags: orocommerce

I'm attempting to create a price list within oro community. I'm not totally familiar with symfony however have managed to write a product assignment rule `product.id in product.product_class == "Class_Name"` then a calculate as `pricelist[15].prices.value * 0.25` where `pricelist[15] = Recommended Retail Price`.

The system starts to calculate and then returns an error:

`Error occurred during price list product assignments build`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be familiar with Symfony to write expressions in the OroCommerce management console. There is documentation and many examples of expressions in OroCommerce:
https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/sales/price-lists/auto/.

The expression `product.id in product.product_class == "Class_Name"` doesn't make much sense as the right expression of `in` operator must be an array, but in your case it's boolean.

Comment: I followed example 1 in the link that you provided and received the same error. I suspect there is a bug preventing this from working.

Comment: You mean `product.id in pricelist[2].assignedProducts` ?

Comment: Was able to get this to work with rule: product.product_class == "Class_Name", calculate as: pricelist[15].prices.value * 0.65 and condition: pricelist[15].prices.quantity == 0